# "FillDown" code being ignored when executing

Tags: excel, vba

I've been programming in VBA for some time now and a recurring problem keeps happening with my code: When executing, more often than not the VBA compiler completely ignores my "FillDown" lines that are meant to pass formula between rows.

This happens mainly when the FillDown line is near a code that gets data from another workbook, for example:

```
Dim wsDb as Worksheet
Dim wsDb2 as Worksheet
Dim wbSAP as Workbook

Set wsDb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Db")
Set wsDb2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Db2")

'Opens a second workbook, gets data from it and close it.

Set wbSAP = Workbooks.Open(Path)
lastLineSAP = wbSAP.Worksheets(1).Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
wbSAP.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(5, 3), Cells(lastLineSAP, 44)).Copy _
Destination:=wsDb2.Cells(lastLineBefore + 1, 2)
wbSAP.Close SaveChanges:=False

'Returns to my original workbook and tries to FillDown some cells

wsDb.Select
With wsDb
    .Range(.Cells(startLine, 30), .Cells(finishLine, 54)).FillDown
End With
```

This method is the latest version of my efforts to make the FillDown line to be more reliable (the wsDb.Select is solely there for this reason, because I noticed the compiler would ignore this line code a little less if I selected the worksheet first), but in the past I've also tried some other versions without success either, like the one below for example:

```
wsDb.Select
wsDb.Range("AD" & startLine & ":BB" & finishLine).FillDown
```

And that's why I need your help. How do you do it? How can I reliably FillDown my cells in a code mixed with openning and closing other workbooks? Maybe just copying and pasting is better?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to Set an object var `Set wsDb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Db")`

Comment: You're pasting into `wsDb2` not `wsDb`.

Comment: Get rid of `On Error Resume Next` and your problems will become apparent.

Comment: Yeah I edited my post. My original code has correct declarations of wsDb and wsDb2, they are public variables. I just copied then here to make it more readable, but made a mistake doing so. And yes I'm pasting my data into wsDb2 and not wsDb, but I do want to FillDown cells in wsDb instead of wsDb2, because they have vlookup formulas.
And there's no "on error resume next" on this code, it runs just fine without any errors, but ignoring my "FillDown" cells line.

Comment: What are the values of `startLine` and `finishLine`?

Comment: They just represent the range of rows that I want to be filled down. They are declared and given values on another part of the code.
For example: If my database was empty and I just got 1000 lines from my "wbSAP" copied into it, my startLine will be 1 and my finishLine will be 1000.

Comment: Please read up on the site concept of [mcve]. It's very difficult for people to help you if you don't provide a *reproducible* scenario / code...